# AutoUpdate the last five entrys of a table in a MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

On [this page](http://selltter.com/) you see at the bottom a "real time" updates of a twitter search with a very simple but elegant animation, i want to do the same but showing the last five entrys on my MySQL data base, is out there a good way to do this?, maybe a combination of php and jquery?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty straightforward.

**Server side:**

Create a PHP page which selects the latest 5 rows from your database and outputs them as JSON.

```
//connect to db

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY some_timestamp_column DESC LIMIT 5");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Client side:**

Every X seconds, make an AJAX request to your PHP script to get the 5 newest rows. Compare them to the ones you've already displayed and add the newer ones to the top of the 'update area'. You can use jQuery to do this.